# How we can update the DOM in react-app whenever a data changes in database?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How we can update the DOM in react-app whenever a data changes in database ?.

I have scenario assume like Shopping app where user can buy a product and purchase. So, Once the user view single product (i.e Single Product Page) and find that the price is 2000, now he wish to purchase the product and move the item into cart(i.e Cart Page).Now i change the price in DB from 2000 to 2500 but in Cart Page i am still see the old price i.e. 2000. I am also using redux to store the Cart item. So, overall my issue is how we can get the updated price value in Cart Page without refreshing the App ? Basically wanted to update in real-time if any value i changes in DB manually or other way?

SingleProduct.js (Page)

```
const SingleProduct = ({ product, onStarClick, star }) => {
  const { title, images, slug, description, _id } = product;
  const [tooltip, setTooltip] = useState("Click to Add");

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const { user, cart } = useSelector((state) => ({ ...state }));

  const handleAddToCart = () => {
    // create cart Array
    let cart = [];
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      // if cart is in localStorage GET it
      if (localStorage.getItem("cart")) {
        cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"));
      }
      // push new product to cart
      cart.push({
        ...product,
        count: 1,
      });
      // remove duplicate
      let unique = _.uniqWith(cart, _.isEqual);
      // save to local storage
      localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(unique));
      setTooltip("Added");

      // item push into Cart as array of object. Here Suppose price of item is 2000 when it add to redux. Suppose after 2min he decide to go Cart Page during that time price got change in DB from 2000 to 2500. But Redux still have Old price value of item.
      dispatch({
        type: ADD_TO_CART,
        payload: unique,
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="col-md-7">
         <Card
          actions={[
            <Tooltip title={tooltip}>
              <a onClick={handleAddToCart}>
                <ShoppingCartOutlined className="text-danger" /> <br /> Add to
                Cart
              </a>
            </Tooltip>,
            <Link to={`/product/${slug}`}>
              <HeartOutlined className="text-info" /> <br />
              Add to Wishlist
            </Link>,
            <RatingModal>
              <StarRating
                name={_id}
                numberOfStars={5}
                rating={star}
                changeRating={onStarClick}
                isSelectable={true}
                starRatedColor="red"
              />
            </RatingModal>,
          ]}
        >
          <ProductListItems product={product} />
        </Card>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default SingleProduct;
```

Cart.js (Page)

```
const Cart = ({ history }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  
  // Here Cart is getting from Redux. And we want the updated price in cart Array of object if value of price change in DB. But i am still getting 2000 value of price not 2500
  const { user, cart } = useSelector((state) => ({ ...state }));

  const showCartItems = () => (
    <table className="table table-bordered">
      <thead className="thead-light">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Image</th>
          <th scope="col">Title</th>
          <th scope="col">Price</th>
          <th scope="col">Brand</th>
          <th scope="col">Color</th>
          <th scope="col">Count</th>
          <th scope="col">Shipping</th>
          <th scope="col">Remove</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      {cart.map((p) => (
        <ProductCardInCheckout key={p._id} product={p} />
      ))}
    </table>
  );
  return (
  <div className="col-md-8">
          <h4>Cart / {cart.length} Product</h4>
          {!cart.length ? (
            <p>
              No products in cart. <Link to="/shop">Continue Shopping</Link>
            </p>
          ) : (
            showCartItems()
          )}
        </div>
)
}
```

Comment: There would only be 2 ways, generally, to get a price update on a live page: 1) make a request for it (the problem here is that your page wouldn't know WHEN to make a request for it, so you'd either have to do long polling or request periodically), or 2) use websockets

Comment: But the problem with (2) is that, with shopify, you're probably not in control of the server itself, so if you wanted web sockets you might have to create a proxy app

Comment: From a user experience point of view, would you really be happy to add a `$2,000` product to your cart and then a few seconds later you realize that it's `$2,500`?